# How to update one SQL reference from one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table I need all value from colE to update to colA is it possible to do it with one SQL?

**TableA**

```
colA    colB    colC    colD    colE
 a       b       x       y       z
 b       c       d       f       h
 c       d       f       w       v
 v       f       f       f       f
```

to update `colA` with value from `colE`

**TableA**

```
colA    colB    colC    colD    colE
 z       b       x       y       z
 h       c       d       f       h
 v       d       f       w       v
 f       f       f       f       f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is too simple:

```
update tableA set colA = colE;
```

Comment: 4 upvotes for an `update ... set val1 = val2;`? This is funny.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code:

```
update TableA
set colA = colE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update table like this

```
update tableA set 
colA = colE;
```

it will update as you want

Answer (score 0):

update [table]
set [colA] = [colE]

should work for you :) try on some test data before live data though